# regex capture string only if keyword does not contain specific character

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, netlogo

I try to create a regex to capture some keyword for netlogo langage, in order to create a file for [highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js). I'm not specialiste of regex, but i try to do that because there is no web syntax highlighter for this langage at this time.

I try a regex which capture all (`[a-zA-Z0-9_\.?=\*!<>:#\+/%\$\^\'&-]*`), but in reality i want only to capture the first (first line of exemple bottom), and exclude any keyword  with special character in it.

```
random --> want to capture only this keyword
#random 
?random
random?
ran?dom
rand#om
random#
```

Only the first line (`random`) need to be captured by the final regex. Other line are authorized name of variable in netlogo, but are not keywords recognized.

**UPDATE 1 :** 
It seems hightlight need to transform /w to //w, for each special regex command.

The entire proposition in comment `(^|\s)(\w+)(?=\s|$)` don't work directly in hightlight.js. I try `(^|\\s)(\\w+)(?=\\s|$)` but in this case any keyword is selected :-/

The partial `lexemes: '(\\w+)(?=\\s|$)'` work but capture only parts of the use case. For example, `random#` is highlighted.

Comment: What is the regex you tried? Please post it in the question body.

Comment: oups, i correct the post

Comment: It seems to me you need something like [`(^|\s)(\w+)(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/nR2bA0/1). You will get hold of your value accessing the Capture Group 1.

Comment: Yay, it work on the regex101 site, but not with **highlighter.js** lexeme regex parser [here](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/language-guide.html?highlight=lexem#keywords)

Comment: I think you can only do it by changing the source code.

Comment: I ask the question directly on github, i post the answer here when it's done.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i update my question with new elements.

Comment: This way you will never achieve what you need. There is no lookbehind in JS, thus you need to get to the highlighter code and make sure you match tokens with `(^|\s)(\w+)(?=\s|$)`, then you only wrap with highlighting tag the Capture Group 2 (captured with `(\w+)`). Without that, you are stuck forever.

Comment: ok @WiktorStribiżew , i update the issue [here](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/issues/1051), but at this time i have no answer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try: `^(\s*)\w+(\s|$)`

in java ,`\` maybe should write as `\\`

Regex in Regexbuddy-Picture:

[image]